# In a Spring HandlerInterceptor, how to get access to the method's parameters/arguments?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop, spring-el

I intend to write my own @RoleRestricted annotation for Spring MVC contoller methods, in order to so something like Spring Security. I want to integrate to Spring Security later, but right now, I have to have my own solution. Plus, this is also a learning question.

I'm using a `HandlerInterceptor` in Spring 3.2, so my `Object handler` is an instance of `HandlerMethod`.

Now, what I want to achieve is to be able to use SpEL expressions in some of the annotation's parameters, which in general works well, using the `hm.getBean()` as root bean for the SpEL evaluation context.

What would be great is to be able to use handler method parameters as SpEL variables, too! E.g. a languageId may be specified as a request parameter and become a handler parameter with `@RequestParam`.

I tried to have a look at the approach of Spring caching, when generating key's from method parameter values, but I found that this codes passes an `Object[] args` along, that comes from an `invoke()` method from some org.aopalliance package. Is there a way to get the `Object[] args` using only Spring AOP?

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception
{
    if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod)
    {
        HandlerMethod hm = (HandlerMethod) handler;

        RoleRestricted annotation = hm.getMethodAnnotation(RoleRestricted.class);

        if (annotation != null)
        {
            // Handler method was annotated with an @RoleRestricted annotation.
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();

            RoleResource resource = annotation.resource();
            EvaluationContext context = ???

            if (SessionUtils.hasRoleLanguageAccess(annotation.resource(), session, annotation.corporateId(), annotation.languageId()))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                logger.debug("Declined access");
                response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL("/RoleLogin.do?onSuccess=" + URLEncoder.encode(onSuccess, "UTF-8")));
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: A `HandlerInterceptor` isn't Spring AOP, Spring AOP is the `MethodInvocation` with the `Object[]`. You should be using such a thing (or an AspectJ based aspect) to prevent the calling of the method, throw an exception and probably have a `HandlerExceptionResolver` act upon that exception. However I would strongly advice against this and simply use and learn Spring Security (instead of this in-between step, which basically reinvents the wheel again).

Comment: Thanks! I agree on Spring Security. Will do when I find the time. So, that package org.aopalliance is part of Spring? An exception would be a nice idea, too. I'll see what I can do, it works nicely with the HandlerInterceptor now, except for the parameters' values, which I may be living with.

Comment: The package `org.aopalliance` isn't really part of spring but was conceived during development of spring. It once had a higher goal but now only Spring uses it (and only in older interceptors). In general it is advised to use the (more powerful) AspectJ aspects for that.